# How to display first element of array using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a function `getFriends`, which return array result. In another file, I have a varaible `userId` which store session id user. And I want to compare first element of array with variale `userId`. I use `array_splice` function that cut another elements of array. But  now varaible `cut` return all elements array, but should only first element. Someone help me  resolve this problem, that variable `cut` return only first element of array ?

```
public function getFriends(int $id, int $sessionId): array
{
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("
        SELECT user.user_id, avatar, first_name, last_name
        FROM user
        JOIN friend ON user.user_id = friend.request_from_id
        where request_to_id = :id AND friend.status='znajomy'
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT user.user_id, avatar, first_name, last_name
            FROM user
            JOIN friend ON user.user_id = friend.request_to_id
            where request_from_id = :id AND friend.status='znajomy'");
    $sql->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':session', $sessionId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();

    $friends = [];
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        $friends[] = new Friend(
            $row['user_id'],
            $row['avatar'],
            $row['first_name'],
            $row['last_name']);
    }
    return $friends;
}
```

```
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$friends = $displaying->getFriends($id->getUserId(), $userId);

$cut = array_slice($friends, 0, 1);

if ($cut != $userId) {
    $result = true;
} else {
    $result = false;
}
```

Comment: `return $friends[0];` will return first element.

Comment: `return current($friends);`

Comment: `current($friends);` return all array, `object(Mess\Application\Friend)#7 (4) { ["userId"]=> int(2) ["avatar"]=> string(10) "avatar.jpg" ["first_name"]=> string(3) "Jan" ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Nowak" }`

Comment: `$cut = array_slice($friends, 0, 1);` should give you the first member of the array only. And that's what it seems to do, same as `current`, since you have a single `Friend` *object* in your dump above. Do `var_dump($friends)` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not reference the first element by checking at array index 0?

```
$cut = $friends[0];
```

Comment: I use `$cut = $friends[0]`, but it not working, becasue  `var_dump($cut)` display all array.